# Reducing 3-Coloring to 10-Coloring (NP-completeness)

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

I am trying to show that the NP-Complete problem of 3-coloring a graph reduces to the problem of 10-coloring a graph.I have already shown how 10-coloring can be verified in polynomial time, and is thus in NP. Now I just need to show it indeed can be reduced to 3-coloring.

My thinking was to essentially prove a bi-conditional: given a graph G, we have that G has a 3-coloring iff G has a 10-coloring. Now, I am not sure how to go about showing this since, fairly obviously, G could have a 10-coloring and not a 3-coloring. So this leads me to believe that there must be some reduction that alters G in some way that lets me see that, yes, 3-coloring does reduce to 10-coloring. Problem is, I am having a difficult time visualizing this.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Math site

Comment: But it is a theoretical computer science question... is it not?

Comment: NP-completeness is a branch of computer science research in and of itself!

Comment: Yes but this site is about programming, not pure graph theory that makes more sense in the Math site. So I suggest you ask your question there you will have more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take your given Graph `G` and complement it with an instance of `K_7` such that for each vertex pair `(u, v) \in G x K_7` an edge be added to form a new Graph `G'`. This enhancement can obviously be done in polynomial time.

- If `G` is 3-colorable, `G'` is 10-colorable:
  Take a 3-coloring of `G`, use 7 other colors to color the `K_7` instance.
- If `G` is not 3-colorable, `G'` is not 10-colorable:
  The instance of `K_7` in `G'` consumes 7 colors. None of these colors may occur in `G`, as there is an edge between each pair of vertices from `G` and the `K_7` instance, respectively.
   
  Consider an arbitrary 3-color assignment on `G`. Since `G` is not 3-colorable, there must be edges `((x_i, y_i)_i=1..m` whose vertices are given the same color under this assignment.
  Assume that we re-color all vertices `{x_i, y_i}_i=1..m` simultaneously. However, no vertex' new color may be among the colors used for the `K_7` instance nor among the 3 colors used for vertices of `G` ( in the latter case the assignment restricted to `G` still would not be admissible after the recoloring). Therefore we would need an 11th color.